# How to compile with an executable (exe) in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, compilation

I'm relatively new with Linux. I'm developing a game in windows and I compile the project with various .exe files (it's a Toshiba TCH900 compiler, made around the year 2000).

I copied the project to my laptop with ubuntu and I would like know if a method exists to use these .exe files to compile the project in linux.

Thanks

Comment: Windows and Linux are two different operating systems, with different formats for their executable files. That aside, what made you pick that specific compiler instead of one of the three major ones (GCC and Clang which are portable and exists both for Windows and Linux, and the Windows specific MSVC compiler)?

Comment: You might like to try Wine to run your Windows executable. However, I don't understand what you mean by "_use this .exe's files to compile_". Do you want to run the Windows compiler in Ubuntu? Which compiler in what version is this?

Comment: Well, the reason for use this specific compiler it's because it's for build Neo Geo Pocket console games. Toshiba made this compiler for build compatible software with her own chip, Toshiba TCL900 (used for this console). I would like if I'll be able to use this compiler for Windows in Linux across some method

Comment: You typically compile source code to build object files.  Object files can be linked to build an executable.  What do you mean by "compile ... with ... .exe files"?

Comment: I mean that the compiler it's a exe file. I give the code file as param and then the compiler build a file

Comment: No, you can't just run Windows executables on Linux. As already suggested, take a look at wine.

Answer (score 0):

if its a simple C program you can use

```
gcc source.c -o myexe
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I'm not asking how to generate a .exe file

Answer (score 0):

I **solved** this isue **using wine**. In my makefile I call at executeble files putting previous wine command.

This works for me and now I'll be able to compile in Linux using .exe files.

Thansk at all.